# what is the purpose of passing a value by reference to a function?

Tags: c++, arraylist, reference

Here is an example:

"ArrayList.cpp"

```
.....
...
..
void Stack::putSurname(employee& e)
{

cout<<"Insert SURNAME"<< endl;
cin >> e.surname;
}
......
....
..
void Stack::push(employee e)
{
pos++;
employeeList[pos] = e;

}
......
....
..
```

"ArrayList.h"

```
.......
.....
..
struct employee
{

string name, surname;
int age;

};

class Stack
{

public:

employee employeeList[1000];

int pos =-1;


public:

bool isEmpty();

void push(employee e);
....
......
........
```

In the function putSurname, why do I have to pass the variable employee by reference in order to see a change in the employeeList array?

Is the purpose of passing a variable by reference that the location in memory of that variable changes every time I call the function, so I allocate different stored variables each time?

Comment: His English isn't so great, but that's no reason not to try to answer his question. At least don't downvote it just because it needs an edit or two.

Comment: downvote only for English?

Comment: It looks like it. I think I can tell what you're asking, but could you clarify your last sentence? I've submitted edits fixing the rest of your grammar, so we'll see if the peer review goes through.

Comment: In the second question I intended to ask if i ' m right thinking :

Comment: I got that part, but your grammar is so weird that I can't actually tell what you're thinking. Could you reword it? If you do, edit your original post please, so everyone can see it right away.

Comment: that the pourpose of passing a variable by reference is that the location of memory of that variable changes everytime i call the function so i allocate each time different stored variables

Comment: that s better? I would have hard time also to speack in my language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's imagine the following scenario.

```
employee emp;
employee& e2 = emp;
```

Then, `e2` becomes a reference variable to `emp`. You can use `e2` to change the object `emp`.

Consider your `putSurname` method

```
void Stack::putSurname(employee& e)
{
    cout<<"Insert SURNAME"<< endl;
    cin >> e.surname;
}
```

You have to call that function as below.

```
employee emp;
putSurname(emp);
```

Then in your method `putSurname`, `e` will be act as a reference variable to `emp`, and whatever changes you do to `e` will be reflected to `emp`.

If your method was as follows.

```
void Stack::putSurname(employee e)
{
    cout<<"Insert SURNAME"<< endl;
    cin >> e.surname;
}
```

You still can call the method as

```
employee emp;
putSurname(emp);
```

But in here, the function will **create a copy** of your `emp` employee object (pass by value) to perform its tasks. Then you know, since it is a copy, the changes will NOT be reflected back to `emp`. And also that variable will be deleted out of the stack after the function execution. Then you will lose any changes done.

Hope this helps.